# Random.randrange() attached to a button

Tags: python, random, tkinter

I need to make a GUI with a button where the button will appear in a random interval of time (from 1 to 10 seconds). I know I need to use the random.randrange() command but I dont know how to.

This is my code so far:

```
#Importere værktøjer
from tkinter import*
import datetime
import time
import os
import datetime
import random

#Tiden
start = time.clock()
finish = time.clock()
elapsed_time = finish - start
t = datetime.datetime.now()


#Definitioner
def myClickMe1():

    label1["text"]='{0:.2f}'.format(elapsed_time)
    print('{0:.2f}'.format(elapsed_time))
    return

#rod defineres
window=Tk()

#Vinduet
window.geometry("700x800")
window.title("Reaktionshastighehs test")

#Labels
label1=Label(window, text="Klik nu!")

#indstillinger til objekter
button1=Button(window, text="Klik her!", command=myClickMe1)

#Placering af objekter
button1.place(x=330, y=460)
label1.place(x=335,y=500)
print(t.second/1000)
```

I wany my button1 to appear at a random time from 1 to 10 seconds. Can anyone help me plsease?

Thanks

Kasper

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter has an [after](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method that you can run on your root window that will call a function after an amount of time (in milliseconds).

[Random](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/random.html#random.randint) has a `randint()` method that can return an integer between two numbers.

So, call `after` and pass a `randint` between 0 and 10 seconds, then call the function to create the `Button`:

```
def placeButton():
    Button(window, text='Click').pack()

window.after(random.randint(0,10000), placeButton)
```